# Create aliases to boost::shared_ptr via reference

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, reference, shared-ptr

I have a small segment of code that I need to optimize.  Thread 'A' has created a boost shared_ptr to a heap object.  Thread 'A' writes the shared_ptr to a thread safe queue.  Thread 'B' reads the shared_ptr, uses it, and then destroys it.

Intense profiling/testing proves that the copying of the shared_ptr going in/out of the queue and adjusting reference counts is costly.  Therefore, I would like to pass the shared ptr to the queue via reference.  I would also like to use std::move to move the shared_ptr into the queue rather than construct a new shared_ptr, (I know this will invalidate the shared_ptr parameter which was passed to the queue).

Everything described works fine until I mix in a dash of polymorphism.  I can't pass by ref a shared_ptr to a derived obj to a function expecting a shared_ptr to a base class.  I have boiled this down to a very small snip that exposes the behavior that confuses me.

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

class Base
{
};

class Derived : public Base
{
};

int main()
{
  boost::shared_ptr<Derived> pDerived(new Derived());  // simple creation
  boost::shared_ptr<Derived> &alias1 = pDerived;       // works fine
  const boost::shared_ptr<Base> &alias2 = pDerived;    // also works fine
  boost::shared_ptr<Base> &alias3 = pDerived;          // compilation error

  //native pointers
  Derived *alias4 = pDerived.get();     //works
  const Base *alias5 = pDerived.get();  //works
  Base *alias6 = pDerived.get();        //works

  //native references
  Derived &alias7 = *pDerived;          // works
  const Base &alias8 = *pDerived;       // works
  Base &alias9 = *pDerived;             // works
}
```

I do not understand why the assignment to alias2 is perfectly fine, yet the assignment to alias3 yields a compiler error.  Can someone please explain this?  I need functionality like the alias3 example and can't make it work.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<Base>& alias3 = static_cast<std::shared_ptr<Base>>( pDerived );`

Comment: You could also try to use boosts `static_cast`: `alias3 = boost::static_pointer_cast<Base>(pDerived);`

Comment: Just like Eissa N. suggested, the cast results in a compilation error: `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type âboost::shared_ptr<Base>&â from an rvalue of type âboost::shared_ptr<Base>â  
       boost::shared_ptr<Base> &alias3 = boost::static_pointer_cast<Base>(pDerived);`  Even if this did work, the creation of the temporary rval object is exactly what I am trying to avoid for efficiency reasons.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not related to boost or smart pointers. It can happen with POD types too as shown in the following simple example:

```
int main() {
    int x = 0;
    const double &y = x; //fine
    double &z = x; //error!
    return 0;
}
```

The reason is that a temporary value (rvalue) can bind to a `const&` but it cannot bind to a `&`. What happens in `double &z = x` is that `x` and `z` are unrelated types, and `x` needs to be converted to a `double` and a temporary variable is created, which cannot bind to a `&`.

Comment: Eissa N. -- I suspect you are totally correct; thank you.  However, see the additional lines added to the example.  Native pointers and references don't seem to require the creation of the temporary rval as you suggest, (probably because the compiler natively understands member offsets in the concatenated structs).  Perhaps this is just another way that shared_ptr containers/templates are not clean replacements for their native counterparts.

Comment: @njensen If you are comparing raw pointers with smart pointers, you should check `Derived* pDerived = new Derived; Base* &alias = pDerived;` which again fails.

Comment: I'd up vote you if I could; apparently I'm too new to have my vote count.  I agree your last example exposes the problem precisely.

Comment: @njensen Also, on another note: `Base` and `Derived` are related types (through inheritance), so binding them as in `Base &alias9 = *pDerived;` works fine. However, `Base*` and `Derived*` are still unrelated types, so binding them using `&` will fail.